# Get parameter from URL in java code in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I've got some problems with obtaining parameter from URL in java code. I've got URL like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:7101/Application6-ViewController-context-root/faces/view1?_adf.ctrl-state=x8y1lwhxd_3&ttt=ttt
```

and all i wanted to do is read the value from the url (parameter ttt should give ttt as result).

I have Java class and JSF page (which contains one button). And after clicking that button I want to print ttt paramter in the console.
I've tried something like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
System.err.println("GET :" + request.getParameter("ttt"));
```

but the output is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
`Map <String,String> map=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();` 
`String tttValue=map.get("ttt");`